# Using query for table names in another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I'm trying to query a database that has a strange manual partition scheme.  The database has a partitions table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partitions](
    [pname] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [drvid] [int] NULL,
    [start_time] [bigint] NULL,
    [end_time] [bigint] NULL,
    [blocksize] [int] NULL,
    [flags] [int] NULL
)
```

And then several of the same table with table names residing in this table.

```
(sql_data_1_2014_05, sql_data_1_2014_06, etc.)
```

So I'd like to be able to write a view that pieces all of the tables together with a union, but I don't know how to pull the table name out of the partition table and use that in my query...  So kinda like the following but in a loop pulling tables names our of the partition table.

```
SELECT
     ....
FROM dbo.sql_data_1_2014_05

    UNION ALL

SELECT
    ....
FROM dbo.sql_data_1_2014_05
```

Also I don't even know if this is the fastest/most efficient way to do this.  These tables are pretty large, hence the partitioning of them.  Any pointers/ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could build a dynamic SQL string for each table, but *should* you do this on tables you claim are massive?  That I don't know...

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @pname nvarchar(max)

set @sql=''

declare pname cursor local
for
select distinct pname from partitions
open pname
fetch next from pname into @pname
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @sql = @sql + 'select col1, col2, col3 from ' + @pname + ' union all '
  fetch next from pname into @pname
end

set @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql)-10)
select @sql
```

[SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9c28/5)

Instead of `SELECT @SQL` you'd want to change to `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL` to run it.

As a test you can copy the resulting string to a new window to test.

Comment: I've used this approach on a similar schema previously.  You'll want to re-create the view(s) as the last step in the job which creates new partitions or drops expired ones.

Comment: Did it make the view super slow?  I'm half considering coding a custom application take care of querying this...

Comment: I've tried this in a data warehouse, and the view was slow as molasses in January.  It was much faster to programatically determine what table was needed on the fly, and query every table individually.